# Event when application is about to be shut down in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

My application uses the `docview` framework provided by *wxWidgets*. In the `OnClose()` method of my `wxView`-derived class I have to know whether only this single window is about to be closed or the whole application gets shut down. (I have to do some housekeeping work before all the windows get closed.)

Is there any event being fired when the application is exiting, before the views are getting closed?

I tried to set a flag in `wxApp::OnExit()`, but `OnExit()` is called only after all the windows have been closed already, so this doesn't work.

**Update for some clarification:** I don't want to know who initiated the closing of the application. I need to find out in `wxView::OnClose()` if the user just closes this single window or the application as a whole.

Comment: Cant you just catch wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW for both the wxDocument and wxView classes?

Comment: At least on macOS, wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW is only fired when clicking the small red close window button, while it's not fired using the shortcut CMD+w or the corresponding menu item.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a solution that's possibly a workaround, but seems to work well, at least on macOS. I override `FilterEvent()` in my `wxApp`-derived class:

```
int MyApp::FilterEvent(wxEvent& event) {
    const wxEventType evt_type = event.GetEventType();
    const int evt_id = event.GetId();
    if( evt_type == wxEVT_MENU && evt_id == wxID_EXIT ) {
        m_about_to_quit = true;
    }
}
```

No matter if the user clicks "Appname Menu > Quit Appname" or uses the shortcut CMD+q, the `if` clause is `true` and the flag is set.

Depending on the state of `m_about_to_quit`, I can now distinguish in `wxView::OnClose()` if only this view is closed or the application is about to be shut down and do my housekeeping if necessary.

Note: Using SDI GUI mode, the main frame is shown (at least on macOS). If the user closes that main frame, the application shuts down without setting `m_about_to_quit` to `true`. In this case, you'd need to set `m_about_to_quit` in the `OnClose` event of the main frame, too.

Answer (score 0):

The application can be closed either explicitly by your program or implicitly because the main window is closed by the user. In the latter case you're going to get `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW`, so you could catch it and do whatever you need to do there -- e.g. this is commonly used to propose to save the changes before closing.

Comment: I think that's not what I need. I don't want to know who initiated the closing of the application. I need to find out in `wxView::OnClose()` if the user just closes this single window or the application as a whole.

Comment: The view doesn't know if the application is being closed, so you can't have this information at this level.

Answer (score 0):

[`wxAppConsole::OnExit`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_app_console.html#a5ee60051c92b0b2933258799626a0485) should do the work:

```
    class MyApp : public wxApp {
    public:
        //...
        virtual int OnExit();
        //...
    };


    int MyApp::OnExit() {
        // Perform cleanup or any actions before the application exits
        //...

        // Returning 0 indicates a normal exit, you can return a different value if needed
        return 0;
    }
```